# How to install USB driver after the installing of software

Tags: c#, c++, c, batch-file

I want to install (or at least, do the prepairing for the installing of) a USB driver after my software is installed on the client computer.

I have a small program, written in C# in Visual Studio 2008, and I can install the program using the standard feature in VS2008. This program talks to a hardware device via USB cable. The USB driver is came from ftdi and can be installed when user plugs it in the USB socket. This works fine, but I want the file to be copied during the installation of the software. Once this is done, show message on screen e.g. "Please plug in your USB cable in to the socket and click OK to continue", on which the installing of the driver is automatically carried out from that moment. (The same as when you install the software for a new printer).

Please advice how I can do it. And it's great if you can help me start with some examples.

Great thanks, Henry.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
// szInfDirectory is a directory on the hard drive where your installer copied the driver files to.

TCHAR szInfPath[MAX_PATH]; 
_tcscpy( szInfPath, szInfDirectory );
_tcscat( szInfPath, _T("YourDriver.inf") );

TCHAR szDestinationInfFileName[MAX_PATH];

if( (!SetupCopyOEMInf( szInfPath, szInfDirectory, SPOST_PATH, 0, szDestinationInfFileName, MAX_PATH, NULL, NULL )) )
{
  nResult = ERR_COPYINF_FAILED;
  return;
}

LPCTSTR HardwareIds[] = 
{
  _T("USB\\Vid_123f&Pid_0444"), 
  _T("USB\\Vid_123f&Pid_0555"), 
};
const size_t cbMax = sizeof(HardwareIds) / sizeof(*HardwareIds);    

bool fInnerLoopFailed = false;
for( size_t cb=0; (cb<cbMax) && (!fInnerLoopFailed); cb++ )
{
  BOOL bRebootReqTemp = FALSE;
  if( (!UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices( NULL, HardwareIds[cb], szInfPath, INSTALLFLAG_FORCE, &bRebootReqTemp )) )
  {
    if( ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST == GetLastError() )
    {
      // nothing to do: device not present
    }
    else
    {
      nResult = ERR_UPDATE_DRIVER_FAILED;
      fInnerLoopFailed = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if( fInnerLoopFailed )
{ 
   // error 
   return;
}

// success
```

Comment: Should be noted that this solution is for 32-bit systems only and requires newdev.lib/newdev.h

Answer (score 0):

The relevant API for this is the "SetupAPI", which contains the Driver Install Framework (DIFx). In particular, you probably need the [`DiInstallDriver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

But I'm not sure if you need to show a "click OK to continue" message. If the driver is already installed, Windows will automatically install the USB device as soon as it's plugged in.